# JQuery Serilize Data Input Is Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have form containing a button, when clicked it displays a modal window with another form containing an input and a `send` / `cancel` button.

I want to serialize the data in this modal form and send it to a remote server via AJAX.

For some reason when I look the the console I can't see the serialized data, I can only see `Email=`

Can someone look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong please? Should this work?

**HTML**

```
<form id="feedbackForm">
    <input class="button" id="bad" src="bad.png" type="image">
</form>

<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal" id="modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <form id="emailForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="Email" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button> 
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" id="closeModal" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var request;
          $("#feedbackForm").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var serializedData = $("#emailForm").serialize();
              $('#modal').modal('toggle');
              $("#emailForm").on("submit", function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                      request = $.ajax({
                          url: "MyURL",
                          type: "post",
                          data: serializedData
                      });
                  request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      console.log(serializedData); // displays Email=
                  });
              });
          });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you really binding the `submit` event evey time a click happens on `#feedbackForm`?

Comment: I tried with your code and still print data https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/rvedZy

Comment: the line event.preventDefault() should lead to an error. (since the event is passed as 'e' in the function). Doesn't it lead to an error to your case?

Comment: I'm not even sure what that means. I'm no expert @31piy which is why I came here. I'm trying to teach myself, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @AnastasiosSelmanis but no error is produced. Using Chrome if that makes any difference. I'll make that change now though, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly when the user clicks the touchstart

1. You serialize the form
2. You open the modal containing the form
3. You overwrite the submit event to send your ajax

The thing is that your variable has already been given the values of the form before it is populated with the user data. (If he is opening the modal for the first time)

Just get your data from a function of ajax submit at the correct moment like this:

```
data: getSerializedData()
```

and the function

```
function getSerializedData(){
    return $("#emailForm").serialize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @Anastasios Selmanis That works perfectly :)